# Normalising 18 bit input between 0-9999

Tags: c, normalization, bit

I'm writing a program in which i require to normalise an 18-bit input between 0-9999. This is something i have never come across before,

I have searched the internet and correct me if i am wrong here, but is this as simple as converting the 18-bit binary(000000000000000000) input into a natural number and then divide it by 1000.

Is there is a different and more efficient method ????

Thank you

Comment: Dividing by 1000 would only work if the upper bound for 18-bit values were any number in the range [9999000, 9999999], which it is not (for an unsigned value the upper bound is 262143). So apart from accepting some answers to your previous questions, you should also rethink the math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, what you want to do is multiply your input by `0.03814697265`.

The reasoning is pretty simple: you take your range of inputs (`0`..`2^18`) and split it in `10000` "slices". Thus each slice will have a range of just over `26`. Then if you divide your input from the original range by this `26` (or multiply it by `1`/`26`), you'll get your number in the `0`..`9999` range.

Edit: depending on your background, you may need to know that here I use `^` with the meaning of exponentiation. Might be moot since this question is tagged C and it has no first-class concept of exponentiation, but it's definetly not XOR!

Comment: I'd suggest 0.0381471181759574 instead: 10000 / 0x3ffff

Comment: Oh--I thought you were using the value for 1/26. Now that I understand that your narration doesn't match your constant, your constant sounds fine.

Comment: Oh okay i think i understand this now, thank you i will try this method